# Kubuntu 20.04 sometimes hangs on shutdown and in standby

Tags: kernel, kubuntu, shutdown, 20.04, reboot

I installed Kubuntu 20.04 alongside Windows 10 on my Lenovo Ideapad 5 15ARE. Because of the new APU (AMD Ryzen 5 4500U) the kernel 5.4 does not work. So I started in recovery mode, installed kernel 5.6.0 and set the boot mode in the BIOS to "Legacy" and "Uefi first".
Now Kubuntu is running very well on my laptop. But I have several problems.

The biggest thing is that my laptop sometimes gets stuck on shutdown. It doesn't matter whether I restart it or shut it down. I also tried to shut it down in the terminal with "sudo reboot" or "sudo shutdown", but it still hangs.

If it gets stuck I have a black picture with two messages.

The first is: **AMD-VI: Unable to read / write to IOMMU perf counter.**

The second is: **Problem loading x.509 certificate -65**

The error messages always come up when starting up, even if it can be shut down normally. If the laptop has hung up, it can only be switched off by holding down the switch. I cannot open a terminal with "CTRL + ALT + (FN) + F3".

Sometimes the laptop also hangs when I close it. The screen then turns black, but the lights on the keyboard and the fan remain on. Here it can only be switched off using the switch.

That is the first problem. The second is not that bad.

The laptop does not recognize, or only after a few minutes, that it was plugged in or unplugged. The percentage battery indicator is correct.

The first problem is particularly annoying. Do you have any idea what I can try. I would say that the problem occurs in about one in three cases.

*translated by google translate:)*

Comment: The first issue is supposed to be solved in [Linux Kernel 5.6.4](https://dev.getsol.us/T8884)